# Is it possible to use Apple Watch with AirPods to detect a "left hand double tap" vs a "right hand tap"?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, airpods

The help instructions for AirPods say I can double tap either my left or right ear to perform an action.

Apple Watch already has a setting for left hand usage vs right hand usage, and that is used by the accelerometer to figure out  when it should turn on the display.  To my mind, this feature could be extended to determine which hand is used to double tap a pair of AirPods...

Does the AirPod / Watch hardware support such a theoretical usage?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to accomplish this with the iTunes version of the Apple Watch, but it only works if playing music from your phone, otherwise the watch can't program these tap options by itself.